# Date format change when copying data from csv to Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a csv file with several values: strings, dates, numbers...
A macro (Excel) imports the csv data to a Excel Sheet, all going well but...
In the csv file I have a column for dates like: "8/1/2018" (where 5 is day, 1 is month. Format: d/M/Y), but when I go to the imported data, I see the date like: "1/8/2018" (note day and month permuted). That's annoying because  my Regional Window configuration specify the format: d/M/Y.
Here you can see the line where all happens: bad date conversion:
[image: BreakPoint in the macro execution where you can see Data(2,3) with correct format]

How could I import date data with correct format? Perhaps some dateFormat for the Sheet?

**EDIT**
Here is the code where the file get opened:

```
Sub ImportFile()
Dim sPath As String
'Below we assume that the file, csvtest.csv,
'is in the same folder as the workbook. If
'you want something more flexible, you can
'use Application.GetOpenFilename to get a
'file open dialogue that returns the name
'of the selected file.
'On the page Fast text file import
'I show how to do that - just replace the
'file pattern "txt" with "csv".
sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\2018w02_wbt_exito.csv"

'Procedure call. Semicolon is defined as separator,
'and data is to be inserted on "Sheet2".
'Of course you could also read the separator
'and sheet name from the worksheet or an input
'box. There are several options.
copyDataFromCsvFileToSheet sPath, ";", """", "Hoja1"

End Sub
'**************************************************************
Private Sub copyDataFromCsvFileToSheet(parFileName As String, _
parDelimiter As String, parExcludeCharacter As String, parSheetName As String)

Dim Data As Variant  'Array for the file values

'Function call - the file is read into the array
Data = getDataFromFile(parFileName, parDelimiter, parExcludeCharacter)

'If the array isn't empty it is inserted into
'the sheet in one swift operation.
If Not isArrayEmpty(Data) Then
  'If you want to operate directly on the array,
  'you can leave out the following lines.
  With Sheets(parSheetName)
    'Delete any old content
    ' .Cells.ClearContents
    'A range gets the same dimensions as the array
    'and the array values are inserted in one operation.
    .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)) = Data
  End With
End If
End Sub
'**************************************************************
Public Function isArrayEmpty(parArray As Variant) As Boolean
'Returns False if not an array or a dynamic array
'that hasn't been initialised (ReDim) or
'deleted (Erase).

If IsArray(parArray) = False Then isArrayEmpty = True
On Error Resume Next
If UBound(parArray) < LBound(parArray) Then
   isArrayEmpty = True
   Exit Function
Else
   isArrayEmpty = False
End If

End Function
'**************************************************************
Private Function getDataFromFile(parFileName As String, _
parDelimiter As String, _
Optional parExcludeCharacter As String = "") As Variant
'parFileName is the delimited file (csv, txt ...)
'parDelimiter is the separator, e.g. semicolon.
'The function returns an empty array, if the file
'is empty or cannot be opened.
'Number of columns is based on the line with most
'columns and not the first line.
'parExcludeCharacter: Some csv files have strings in
'quotations marks ("ABC"), and if parExcludeCharacter = """"
'quotation marks are removed.

Dim locLinesList() As Variant 'Array
Dim locData As Variant        'Array
Dim i As Long                 'Counter
Dim j As Long                 'Counter
Dim locNumRows As Long        'Nb of rows
Dim locNumCols As Long        'Nb of columns
Dim fso As Variant            'File system object
Dim ts As Variant             'File variable
Const REDIM_STEP = 10000      'Constant

'If this fails you need to reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
'You select this in "Tools" (VBA editor menu).
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

On Error GoTo error_open_file
'Sets ts = the file
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(parFileName)
On Error GoTo unhandled_error

'Initialise the array
ReDim locLinesList(1 To 1) As Variant
i = 0
'Loops through the file, counts the number of lines (rows)
'and finds the highest number of columns.
Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
  'If the row number Mod 10000 = 0
  'we redimension the array.
  If i Mod REDIM_STEP = 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve locLinesList _
    (1 To UBound(locLinesList, 1) + REDIM_STEP) As Variant
  End If
  locLinesList(i + 1) = Split(ts.ReadLine, parDelimiter)
  j = UBound(locLinesList(i + 1), 1) 'Nb of columns in present row
  'If the number of columns is then highest so far.
  'the new number is saved.
  If locNumCols < j Then locNumCols = j
  i = i + 1
Loop

ts.Close 'Close file

locNumRows = i

'If number of rows is zero
If locNumRows = 0 Then Exit Function

ReDim locData(1 To locNumRows, 1 To locNumCols + 1) As Variant

'Copies the file values into an array.
'If parExcludeCharacter has a value,
'the characters are removed.
If parExcludeCharacter <> "" Then
  For i = 1 To locNumRows
    For j = 0 To UBound(locLinesList(i), 1)
      If Left(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
        If Right(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
          locLinesList(i)(j) = _
          Mid(locLinesList(i)(j), 2, Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 2)
        Else
          locLinesList(i)(j) = _
          Right(locLinesList(i)(j), Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 1)
        End If
      ElseIf Right(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
        locLinesList(i)(j) = _
        Left(locLinesList(i)(j), Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 1)
      End If
      locData(i, j + 1) = locLinesList(i)(j)
    Next j
  Next i
Else
  For i = 1 To locNumRows
    For j = 0 To UBound(locLinesList(i), 1)
      locData(i, j + 1) = locLinesList(i)(j)
    Next j
  Next i
End If

getDataFromFile = locData

Exit Function

error_open_file:  'Returns empty Variant
unhandled_error:  'Returns empty Variant

End Function
```

Comment: This is where I get the file:
`
Dim fso As Variant            'File system object
Dim ts As Variant             'File variable
Const REDIM_STEP = 10000      'Constant

'If this fails you need to reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
'You select this in "Tools" (VBA editor menu).
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

On Error GoTo error_open_file
'Sets ts = the file
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(parFileName)
On Error GoTo unhandled_error`

Comment: Please edit your question to enter the code (as text) since it is not formatted in a comment

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format code. I put it in backticks but not the way...

Comment: **PUT IT IN YOUR ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Comment: OK, I put the code in an edit of the original question.

Comment: @framontb please add the complete sub (or at least all relevant parts) to your original question. Posting only little parts of a code is worth nothing. The part you posted is almost useless without the rest. Also sample import data would me necessary to help you.

Comment: I suggest you **NOT** use the `FSO` for this.  I suggest you record a macro while `Importing` the data and define the DMY parameter there for the appropriate column.  Or you could cycle through the text stream object, check for a date, and convert it appropriately there, but the Import process will be simpler.

Comment: OK, I put little snippets because it is a big piece of code. Now is all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `FileSystemObject` to obtain your data, you will need to convert each date item in your `Data` variable into a "real date" before writing it to the worksheet.

As it is in your screenshot, it is a string and, as you have discovered, the conversion when writing to the worksheet is unreliable.

One way to convert it.

```
Dim V As Variant, i As Long
For i = LBound(Data) To UBound(Data)
    V = Split(Data(i, 3), "/")

    'test for proper date
    If UBound(V) = 2 Then _
        Data(i, 3) = DateSerial(V(2), V(1), V(0))
Next i
```

Might be easier to IMPORT the data rather than using the FSO